How to dump values from chrome://flags/ to a file to compare settings between two Chrome versions
I have Google Chrome production and beta versions loaded on my laptop.  In order to troubleshoot some issue on a web application using https protocol, that would get a resource from a URL using http protocol.  This was probably a couple years ago.  The setting was to allow me the option to access that http resource via the warning page "are you sure you want to access http://example.com/some.js", instead of just not loading it.
Well, later on I wanted to get rid of that flag, and I didn't remember what flag it was.  And now, I am having an issue with the production version of Chrome handling Okta verification using Windows Hello and fingerprint validation, but my beta Chrome version works fine.
So, I'd like to dump out as a text file the chrome://flags/ settings from production Chrome and beta Chrome, to compare them to see if that is causing my current issue.
Is that possible, or is there some other way to accomplish seeing what flags are different?
Versions

Production version: Version 131.0.6778.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Beta version: Version 132.0.6834.6 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)
Laptop: Windows 11 Enterprise (some browser settings set by company)


This answer says they are stored in 
%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State (for Chrome beta it should be \Google\Chrome Beta\
You can open it in some text editor like Notepad++ (prettify as JSON for easier navigation) and look for enabled_labs_experiments. only non-default (changed) values show up there though.

Thanks - I'll check it out Monday.

Thanks for the link to the answer; I searched here with all sorts of terms, except for the right terms!
